# Как получить Json объект из тега <script>?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, json, requests

При помощи библиотеки requests получаю страницу по следующей ссылке: https://pastebin.com/YneDr4id

Каким образом я могу получить Json объект, который записывается в переменную initialState для дальнейшей работы с этим объектом уже в python коде?

Comment: python, requests, bs4, re. Тег `script`, свойство тега `string`, `flags=re.S` ну и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

response = requests.get(
    'https://2gis.ru/voronezh/search/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/firm/4363390420293667/39.202914%2C51.676518',
    headers={
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
    }
)

soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find(
    'script', string=re.compile(r'^.*?var __customcfg.*$', flags=re.S)
).string.replace(r'\\"', r'\"')

# Вот с этим уже можно работать
dict_list = [*map(json.loads, map(lambda x: x.strip("'"), re.findall(r'\'.+?\'', script)))]

# Это дамп для наглядности. Мне, к пиримеру, так проще разбирать словари
json.dump(
    dict_list, 
    open('j.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8'), 
    ensure_ascii=False, 
    indent=2
)

# Теперь про Нужный Вам контент:
script = soup.find(
    'script', string=re.compile(r'^.*?initialState = JSON.parse.*$', flags=re.S)
).string.replace(r'\\"', r'\"')


initial_states_tag = re.search(r'initialState = JSON.parse.*?\'(.+?)\'', script).group(1)

initial_states = json.loads(initial_states_tag)

# Это даст вам искомый JSON в виде словаря в переменную initial_states
```

Дамп получившегося списка словарей, даст приблизительно такой файл
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]